# Is it possible to make a massive call to Google Natural Language API?

Tags: google-cloud-nl

I am using the Natural Language API from Google to analyse the sentiment of some sentences, but it seems that you can only send sentences one by one.

Is it possible to make a massive call of the API? Is it possible to send many sentences in a single call or do I have to make a call for each sentence?

Thank you!

Comment: none of your tags are relevant. also show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a single call with a bunch of sentences in it, we'll automatically split the document into sentences, calculate sentiment for each sentence, and give you an overall weighted average of them for the whole document.

There's a limit on the size of the document, but a few hundred k should be fine.